# Spark scala: How to factorize code with Column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have to join two tables and create new columns. The code is redundant. How can I factorize that with UDF in Spark/Scala.

```
val finaldf : DataFrame =  tableA.join(tableB, col("A_val") === col("B_val"), "left_outer")
.withColumn ("D1", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D1"))
  .otherwise(col("A_D1")))
.withColumn ("D2", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D2"))
  .otherwise(col("A_D2")))
.withColumn ("D3", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D3"))
.otherwise(col("A_D3")))
.withColumn ("D4", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D4"))
.otherwise(col("A_D4")))
.withColumn ("D5", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D5"))
.otherwise(col("A_D5")))
.withColumn ("D6", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D6"))
.otherwise(col("A_D6")))
.withColumn ("D7", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D7"))
.otherwise(col("A_D7")))
.withColumn ("D8", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D8"))
.otherwise(col("A_D8")))
.withColumn ("D9", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D9"))
.otherwise(col("A_D9")))
.withColumn ("D10", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D10"))
.otherwise(col("A_D10")))
```

Thank you for you answer

Comment: coalesce is function in Spark/sql

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution.
Briefly, it creates series of columns then select it after join.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finaldf : DataFrame =  tableA.join(tableB, col("A_val") === col("B_val"), "left_outer")
// create 10 columns 
val cols = (1 to 10).map(s => when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("B_D"+s))
          .otherwise(col("A_D"+s)))
val dfCols = finaldf.columns.map(col) ++ cols
// select original columns and newly created columns
val df = finaldf.select(dfCols:_*)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How would you do if the column names can be any name, it's not D1, D2...  but for example: val finaldf : DataFrame =  tableA.join(tableB, col("A_val") === col("B_val"), "left_outer")
.withColumn ("Person", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("Person"))
  .otherwise(col("Pers")))
.withColumn ("Age", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("Ag"))
  .otherwise(col("G2")))
.withColumn ("Domain", when(col("A_val").isNotNull && col("B_val").isNotNull, col("Dom"))
.otherwise(col("Dma")))

Comment: Instead of (1 to 10), you can start from Seq("person", "age")